# How can I confirm I'm on the home page

Tags: homepage

I have the index.php in themes directory as my homepage. How can I confirm programmatically that the homepage was called in my functions.php? is_home() and is_front_page() is true for other pages and PHP_SELF always shows index.php.

[More info]

What I'm trying to do is show some Google Web Optimizer Control scripts only on the home page (http://example.com/). The B in the A/B test is index-3 (http://example.com/index-3). But what happens is that if I hit our blog pages (http://example.com/blogs) is_home() and is_front_page() is triggering true causing the script to show in the head. I'm not sure what is causing the blogs page to trigger. I'm using the wp_print_scripts event to trigger my function in the functions.php file.

Settings>>Reading is set to "Your latest posts" the home page name is index.php located in the themes directory.

So the final question is "Is there a method to know that the function called is for the home page (http://example.com/) and not another?"

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time guys. All I had to do is look at the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` I got myopic and forgot I could just look at the environment info.

Comment: This appears to be more of a clarification of your question. If you need to *clarify* your question, you should just update your question directly. Otherwise, this becomes an answer to an old version of the question.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the default home page, which in most cases is a list of most recent posts, is_home() should work.

If you have set a static page to be your front page (in Settings >> Reading), is_front_page() should work. If you are not getting the results you expect using this:

```
if (is_front_page()) {
  //the code you want to execute
}
```

perhaps you can describe your situation in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Up-voted @supertrue, but wanted to add some clarification:

- `is_front_page()` returns true when on the **site front page** (what is commonly referred to as the "home" page).
- `is_front_page()` returns true when on the site front page, whether the front page is set to display the **Blog Posts Index** or a **static Page**.
- `is_home()` returns true when displaying the **Blog Posts Index**.
- `is_home()` returns true when displaying the Blog Posts Index, whether on the **Front Page**, or on a **static Page**.
- A useful option for differentiating between **static Page** and **Blog Posts Index** when on the Front Page is `get_option( 'show_on_front' )`, which returns either `page` or `posts`

**EDIT**

> Settings>>Reading is set to "Your
>   latest posts" the home page name is
>   index.php located in the themes
>   directory.

So, based on what I stated above:

- When on the **Front Page**, then `is_front_page()` *always* returns `true`.
- When displaying your **Blog Posts Index** ("your latest posts"), `is_home()` *always* returns `true`.

Your **Front Page** is set to display your blog posts index, thus **both `is_front_page()` and `is_home()`** will return true.

**EDIT 2**

> So the final question is "Is there a
>   method to know that the function
>   called is for the home page
>   (http://example.com/) and not
>   another?"

Yes! That's what `is_front_page()` is for.

If you need to know you're on the *front page*, and that the front page is *static*:

```
if ( is_front_page() && 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) )
```

If you need to know you're on the *front page*, and that the front page is your *blog posts*:

```
if ( is_front_page() && 'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) )
```